# How to add HTML-tags to JS-file

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

I use Expo (React Native) with the main `App.js` file.
It's connected to my base with data called `data.js`.
Example of data.js element:

```
{
  id: '70078463',
  price: '$49.99',
  name: 'PELLO',
  image:
    'https://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/pello-armchair__38296_PE130209_S5.JPG?f=xs'
},
```

I want to add a `description` tag with the information about the item:

```
description: 'This is the best one you can buy online. It is so cool! Why have not you bought it?',
```

In HTML I could use `<p>` tag to make each sentense on a new line. How can I do it here?

Comment: You can use <Text></Text> instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add a description to your JS Object as a new key-value pair you have two options:

```
 let object = {
  id: '70078463',
  price: '$49.99',
  name: 'PELLO',
  image:
    'https://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/pello-armchair__38296_PE130209_S5.JPG?f=xs'
},
```

Using **Dot Notation**:

```
object.description = "value";
```

Or **Square Bracket Notation**:

```
object["description"] = "value";
```

If you know for sure it is always description you can use dot notation but if you want to dynamically add key-value pairs the square bracket notation lets you pass in a variable.